# why does my pygame window not respond after a few seconds?

Tags: python

this is my code and when i run this it just freezes and im not sure why

```
import pygame
import sys



pygame.init()
(5, 0)
#game window
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('battle')


#load images
#background image
background_img = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\olive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\idlelib\created games.package\rpg\img\setting\Background.png").convert_alpha()

#function for drawing background
def draw_bg():
    screen.blit(background_img,(0,0))


run = True

while run:
    #draw background
    draw_bg()

    
for event in pygame.event.get():
 if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
  run = False

            
  pygame.display.update()
          
pygame.quit()
```

i have no clue what to try i use both the latest version of python and the latest version of pygame

Comment: Check your indentation. Your while loop is not doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple indentation error. In Python when writing a while loop the while loop will run all of the code under it when the code has indentation (that being spaces or tabs) for example this would work:

```py
while run:

    dosomething()

    for item in something:
        dootherthing(item)
```

But this wouldn't:

```py
while run:

dosomething()

if something:

dootherthing(item)
```

and even if you got the indentation right the code *logically* doesn't function.

```py
while run:
    dothing()

dootherthing()
# WHILE RUN is TRUE this ^ will not run 
# because while only runs code under it with the correct indentation
```

So in order for your code to function if you want to repeatedly update and listen for any events you need to put it *inside* the while loop so something like this:

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

#(5, 0)
#game window

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('battle')

#load images
#background image
background_img = pygame.image.load(r"C:\Users\olive\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\idlelib\created games.package\rpg\img\setting\Background.png").convert_alpha()

#function for drawing background
def draw_bg():
    screen.blit(background_img,(0,0))

run = True

while run:

    #draw background
    draw_bg()
    
    #while running check for events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            
    #while running update screen
    pygame.display.update()
          
pygame.quit()
```

Have fun writing the rest of your code!

Comment: thank you so much for the help, cant believe I overlooked something so simple works all good now

Comment: @ineedhelp that's great! Could you please mark the answer as correct? It is currently still unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to events, your program must continuously check for events. However, your program is currently drawing your background (forever), and it never actually checks for events.

Assuming your 'not responding' is referring to Windows' 'this application is not responding', I believe that the few seconds it takes to stop responding is actually because Windows is checking if it's not responding. It was, likely, never responding in the first place.

To fix your problem, you need to indent your `for event in pygame.event.get()`. That way, your program checks for events constantly whilst the game runs, which would make the program responsive.